# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie and Request.url failing in Unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I am working on asp.net MVC 4 application and creating unit tests. I have an account controller and register method which has two things:

```
if (this.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("127.0.0"))
{
    user.AddPermission(UserEntity.PermissionType.BETA_ACCESS);
}
```

and

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

Test fails on both these lines. I goggled and found that We can not use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` as FormsAuthentication is a static class so I tried following workaround:

```
public interface IAuthenticationProvider
{
    void SetAuthCookie(string username, bool remember);
}

public class FormsAuthWrapper : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    public void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool remember)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, remember);
    }
}
```

and in controller action I used:

```
_authenticationProvider.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

in test method I used:

```
var wrapper = new FormsAuthWrapper();
AccountController controller = new AccountController(s, config, wrapper);
```

but when i call controller action method, it still gives object reference null error on

```
_authenticationProvider.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

My other issue is related to request.url, I tried this in my test method:

```
controller.ControllerContext = CreateStubControllerContext(controller);

var requestStub = Mock.Get(controller.Request);
requestStub.Setup(r => r.UrlReferrer).Returns(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1"));

var RegisterModel = new RegisterModel { UserName = "test2@cc.com", Password = "testpass", ConfirmPassword = "testpass" };    
controller.Register(RegisterModel);
```

but it throws error on this line in controller action:

```
if (this.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("127.0.0"))
{
    user.AddPermission(UserEntity.PermissionType.BETA_ACCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two distinct questions:

1. You should be using a *mock* of `IAuthenticationProvider` on your test, not the concrete `FormsAuthWrapper`. The latter will never work without a full web context (which you will never get from inside an unit-test).
2. Not so sure about this one, but I guess you are just mocking the wrong property: it should be `Url` instead of `UrlReferrer` (they usually evaluate to the same value, but they do *not* reference the same string object).